# Is script\bin_path.sh missing?

Tags: documentation, build, git

I'm following [these instructions](https://docs.cardano.org/projects/cardano-node/en/latest/getting-started/install.html) to start up cardano-node from source.

After downloading `cardano-node` from GitHub, I see that `script\bin_path.sh` does exist.

After selecting the latest version it still does not.

```
git fetch --all --recurse-submodules --tags
git tag
git checkout tags/1.23.2
```

Then after building, the following instructions fail:

```
cp -p "$(./scripts/bin-path.sh cardano-node)" ~/.local/bin/
cp -p "$(./scripts/bin-path.sh cardano-cli)" ~/.local/bin/
```

Comment: Can you please post the error message. How is it failing?

Comment: I didn't see any error, but it's clearly not going to work because bin_path.sh is referenced and does not exist.    I copied that script from a different branch and it worked.  I need to be added, or the documentation needs to be changed.

Comment: Can you log it as a bug on Git?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `tags/1.23.2`. The most recent release was `tags/1.26.2`. You can see the file on `master` at the moment [0] so I'd suggest checking out a more recent version of `cardano-node` and opening a PR or submitting an issue on GitHub to update the node version that the docs suggest using.

[0] https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/scripts/bin-path.sh

Comment: It's also missing from 1.26.2.

Comment: Just merge the file into 1.26.2 if you need it